# Is it possible to create a shapefile from a csv with pt numbers, lat, lon, elev, and description using js or php?

Tags: csv, gis, shapefile

Is it possible to create a shapefile from a csv with pt numbers, lat, lon, elev, and description using js or php? I have looked around and cant find any information.

Comment: Please don't write question in title, and give better title to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the ogr2ogr commandline tool to accomplish this.  You don't need php.  Using a vrt file, you would be able to define the geometry and other columns you want.

Everything you need to know is explained in details here: http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_csv.html

ogr2ogr is a tool included in GDAL/OGR library.